# Why the materialized view does not contain all data after refreshing through informatica?

Tags: oracle, informatica, materialized-views

I have a stored procedure and materialized view in same DB.The purpose of this procedure is to refresh the materialized view.
When I run the procedure directly from db mview is refreshed properly means the mview returns more data.
Now I done an informatica mapping ,this mapping  call the store procedure to refresh the mview.
It runs properly but mview does not refresh properly that means the mview contains less data rather than first try.
My Question is that why the materialized view does not contain the all data after refreshing through informatica?
materialized view refresh type is complete.

Comment: This seems like something you should be raising with Infomatica.

Comment: Sounds like you have two ways to refresh the MV.  One way is via the DB, perhaps via DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH and this works.  The second way is from your custom procedure, which you call from informatica, and it does not work.  Sounds like your procedure is wrong, which may not even be related to Informatica.  And, since you provided nothing about your procedure, how would you expect this community to help you?

Comment: I am using same (DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH) both time to refresh the MV. Still the number of records getting refreshed is different. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem is that you've not invoked the stored procedure successfully at all but have convinced yourself that you have. Please include the excerpt of the session logs that confirms the stored procedure ran successfully (also check the connection used when the stored procedure call is made is the same as it should be i.e. you may have chosen a connection when writing the mapping but in the workflow it will be set to the default which most likely isnt the same)

Comment: I am using same (DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH) both time to refresh the MV. Still the number of records getting refreshed is different. Please help

Comment: Please if you can share the session log excerpt to demonstrate this and to enable us to help you.